# PyParsing not importing Word or alphas

Tags: python-3.x, pyparsing

OS X 10.9.5, Python 3.4, PyParsing 2.0.3, PyCharm 4.0 CE

I installed PyParsing using easy_install, and see in my PyCharm Project Interpreter panel that it is in there with the rest of the Python 3.4 packages.

I tried running the following "Hello World!" script from the PyParsing wiki:

```
from pyparsing import Word, alphas
greet = Word( alphas ) + "," + Word( alphas ) + "!"
hello = "Hello, World!"
print (hello, "->", greet.parseString( hello ))
```

I get the following errors:

```
File "/Users/..../pyparsing.py", line 1, in <module>
from pyparsing import Word, alphas
ImportError: cannot import name 'Word'
```

The PyCharm code window message says, *"This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items."*

I have tried Googling for similar situations and solutions, but have hit an impasse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't by any chance called your program file "pyparsing.py" have you? If so this will confuse python (It will try to import Word from itself. Try changing the name to something inoffensive like temp1.py

EDIT
Generally avoid using names for files and variable that might confuse both the python interpreter and you.

Comment: Yes, it was pyparsing.py, but I changed it and still get the same error messages. Edit: I shut down the entire session, then restarted it. Now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Everybody does this at least once - welcome to Python (and pyparsing)!